# QListWidget does not emit a signal itemEntered(QListWidgetItem*)

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

In my program, QListWidget be used in more than three place. Only one place, QListWidget does not emit the signal itemEntered(QListWidgetItem*).

My code:

```
MyListWidget::MyListWidget(QWidget* parent):QListWidget(parent)
{
    this->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    this->setMouseTracking(true); 
    connect(this, SIGNAL(itemEntered(QListWidgetItem*)),        
            this, SLOT(slotOnItemEntered(QListWidgetItem*)));
}
MyListWidget::slotOnItemEntered(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    // do something
}
```

When I debug, and move mouse glide the item, the program cannot go in the slotOnItemEntered(...) function.
I want to konw, what condition can cause this phenomenon.

Comment: And at this one place, QListWidget emit signals itemPressed(...),itemClicked(...)...

Answer (score 0):

This problem even don't know the reason. I use answer way to solve the problem.

QWidget has signals:
    enterEvent(...);  // when mouse move in 
    leaveEvent(...);  // when mouse move out

I overwrite these two function, to solve the problem.